# Custom App.Config configSections

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando agregar unos valores customs, fuera de appSettings, por que necesito mapear estos valores y tomarlos como parte de un objeto...

En este mismo foro pero en ingles, leí como hacerlo e intente replicarlo sin éxito.. este es mi App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Configuracion de Email -->
    <add key="UserEmail" value="mail@mail.com" />
    <add key="PasswordEmail" value="123456" />
    <!-- Configuracion de estructura de Email -->
    <add key="SubjetEmail" value="Evento [{0}]" />
    <add key="BodyEmail" value="&lt;font size=3&gt;--- Se ha registrado un evento {0} ---&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;font color=blue&gt;&lt;u&gt;Información detallada&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;b&gt;{1}&lt;/b&gt;" />
  </appSettings>
  <!-- Cadenas de Conexion a DB -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mibasededatos" connectionString="Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=mibasededatos;user id=miusuario;password=mipassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlAddresses" type="namespace.UrlRetrieverSection"/>
  </configSections >
  <!-- URL (Agregar o quitar) -->
  <urlAddresses>
    <add name="Google" url="http://www.google.com" />
  </urlAddresses>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Y la clase UrlRetrieverSection

```
public class UrlRetrieverSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public UrlCollection UrlAddresses
        {
            get
            {
                return (UrlCollection)this[""];
            }
            set
            {
                this[""] = value;
            }
        }
    }


    public class UrlCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new UrlElement();
        }
        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((UrlElement)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public class UrlElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["name"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("url", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Url
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["url"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["url"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Para después leerlo de la siguiente manera

```
UrlRetrieverSection UrlAddresses = (UrlRetrieverSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("urlAddresses");
```

Y ahí viene el problema, al parecer se corrompe la estructura del App.Config, por que el error el error es el siguiente.

**Error en la inicialización del sistema de configuración**

==============================================================

Al final pude corregirlo. El problema es que

```
<configSections>
    <section name="urlAddresses" type="namespace.UrlRetrieverSection"/>
  </configSections >
```

Se debe declarar al inicio del App.Config, justo despues de configuration y antes de appSettings.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola! deberías agregar la forma en como lo resolviste como una respuesta y marcarla como aceptada. Abrazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la ubicación de tu elemento **ConfigSections**, debe ser el primer nodo de tu archivo de configuración.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="urlAddresses" type="namespace.UrlRetrieverSection"/>
  </configSections >
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Configuracion de Email -->
    <add key="UserEmail" value="mail@mail.com" />
    <add key="PasswordEmail" value="123456" />
    <!-- Configuracion de estructura de Email -->
    <add key="SubjetEmail" value="Evento [{0}]" />
    <add key="BodyEmail" value="&lt;font size=3&gt;--- Se ha registrado un evento {0} ---&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;font color=blue&gt;&lt;u&gt;Información detallada&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;b&gt;{1}&lt;/b&gt;" />
  </appSettings>
  <!-- Cadenas de Conexion a DB -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mibasededatos" connectionString="Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=mibasededatos;user id=miusuario;password=mipassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- URL (Agregar o quitar) -->
  <urlAddresses>
    <add name="Google" url="http://www.google.com" />
  </urlAddresses>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Mayor información [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2tw134k3.aspx) en MSDN.

Comment: Gracias por responder, es correcto al poco rato de intentar todo, di con la respuesta, edite mi pregunta y abajo puse la respuesta. Aun así gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo único extraño que veo es a la hora de registrar el tipo de sección en el app.config:

```
<section name="urlAddresses" type="namespace.UrlRetrieverSection"/>
```

¿Tu namespace se llama "namespace"?

Comprueba en el archivo de la clase UrlRetrieverSection en qué namespace se encuentra. En principio será por defecto el nombre de la aplicación.

Por ejemplo si tienes:

```
namespace MiAplicacion
{
    public class UrlRetrieverSection: ConfigurationSection
```

La línea en el app.config debería ser:

```
<section name="urlAddresses" type="MiAplicacion.UrlRetrieverSection"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Si, en esa parte le pongo el namespace de mi aplicación, le cambie a namespace para ponerlo aquí.